# How to properly substitute my variable so that these two integrals are equivalent?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm having troubles figuring out if what I'm doing is mathematically correct.

I replaced the $\theta$ term in my multidimensional numerical integral by giving it a functional dependence of the angle $\beta$ such as $\theta\left(\beta\right)$. Now, the angle $\theta$ goes from $[0,\pi]$, while $\beta$ goes from $[0,\pi/2]$. I made the substituion in my integral and the only term that seems to go wrong is the $\sin(\theta)$.

Usually I would integrate like this:

$\int_0^{\pi}~f(\theta)\sin(\theta)~d\theta$,

and now I'm trying to do this :

$\int_0^{\pi/2}~f(\theta(\beta))~\sin(\theta(\beta))~d\beta$.

Now, those two integrals should deliver me the same result, but they don't. I figured out that if I multiply the $\beta$-dependent integral by a factor of two or change the integration limits to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, I end up with the desired result.

So I am clearly failing with my substitution but I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or what am I not taking into account. Do I need to calculate my integration element $d\beta$ and the integration limits in another way? However, $\beta$ needs to be kept in this range $[0,\pi/2]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the chain rule, $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)}f(g(x))\frac{dg}{dx}dx$. So you need an extra factor of $\frac{d\theta}{d\beta}$ in your integrand.

Comment: Alright so the correct form would be: $\int_{\sin^{-1}(\theta(\beta=0))}^{\sin^{-1}(\theta(\beta=\pi))}~f(\theta(\beta))~\sin(\theta(\beta))~\frac{d\theta}{d\beta}~d\beta$ . Are these the right values for the integration limits? Even thou i want my beta to go from $[0,\pi/2]$

Comment: Could you also be so kind as to pass me a link where I can read more on the theory of making such substitutions and how to change the limits? I will need also for multidimensional integrals

Comment: Since theta is a function that relies on a beta, you want your inputs of your bounds to match in both integrals. i.e. $f(\theta(\theta^{-1}(b)))=f(b)$. I'd recommend looking here for a cursory look at change of variables for the 1D case: [link](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/SubstitutionRuleDefinite.aspx) and here for the multivariable version: [link](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/ChangeOfVariables.aspx). If you want something more rigorous, you'd be able to find a good summary of the 1D version in any introductory analysis book.